# Displaying direction of water system with arrows in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, flow-direction

I would like to put direction arrows next to my Water system just like in OpenTopoMap (see the image under).

[image: Screenshot from Opentopomap]

I already watched the source code but they made it with Mapnik. However, I am working on my maps in QGIS.

In QGIS there are arrows line. I can put it next to my flow, but they are stick one after the another. I would like to have separated arrows by a certain distance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this result with styling.

Take the water line layer style and add a new `symbol layer`, select `marker line` and display it on `central point`

[image]

Select the `marker` layer, select the arrow symbol (at this point you can also import another svg symbol if the default arrow doesn't suit your needs), set its color. Beside the `rotation` setting, <s>click the `data defined override` button / `edit` and enter the following equation, which compute the line angle at the center of the line.</s>

```
line_interpolate_angle(  $geometry , $length /2)
```

**EDIT** thanks to @J.R comment, you can just put 90 instead of computing the angle

[image]

At last, select the `simple marker` layer and put an adequate offset, maybe 2 mm

[image]

Comment: If you need to have equally spaced marker just choose the "with interval" radio button and set the interval. Also you dont need to set the rotation with a formula, the symbol should follow the curvature of your line (if your arrow is perpendicular to your line set the rotation to 90 or -90 to point in the right direction). Also dont forget to set a line offset to display the arrow on the side of the line.